# Disable HTML link hover color

Tags: html, css

If I have a `<div>`, I can control its color like this:

```
<div class="good">Hello</div>
.good { color: green; }
```

I want to do the same thing for links, like this:

```
<a href="...", class="good">Hello</a>
.good { color: green; }
```

I want the link to be green, even when mouse hover happens, like the `<div>`. I know I can do this:

```
.good:hover { color: green; }
```

But that means I have to remember to add that for every single class that may be applied to `<a>` element. Is there a simple way to disable hover color change for `<a>`? I'm thinking about something like:

```
a:hover { color: do-not-change; }
```

or:

```
a:hover { color: inherit-from-non-hover; }
```

**Update**
I forgot to mention that I did set global `a` and `a:hover` to override the browser default:

```
a, a:hover { color: black; text-decoration: none; }
```

This is because I don't know how to disable hover color. Ideally what I want is:

```
a { color: black; }
a:hover { color: <some way to tell it to not change>; }
.good { color: green; }
```

Then `<a>` is black, hover or not. And `<a class="good">` is green, hover or not.

Comment: Stays green for me even when hovering. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eew6rqzw/

Comment: If you don't set a global hover state (a:hover) then you don't need to define .good:hover, it will be the same color as .good.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `inherit` or `initial` property, but that will lead into black color on hover or what ever color property is applied to the immediate parent element of the anchor tag .

```
a:hover{
    color: inherit; /* Inherits color property from its parent */
}

a:hover{
    color: initial; /* Takes initial value of the property which is black in this case */
}
```

Comment: This is NOT what I want. I want to use the same color of the same element's non-hover color, not parent's color.

Comment: @cnshenj I had the same issue. Instead of using `color: initial` on the a:hover you can just  add `!important` on the `a { color }` itself, eg: `a { color: white !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this...

Create a new class that can be used on any element where :hover might be a different color:

```
<div class="good nochange">Hello</div>
<a href="..." class="good nochange">Hello</a>
.nochange:hover{
    color:inherit;
}
```

Add it to your class `good`:

```
<a href="..." class="good">Hello</a>
.good:hover{
    color:inherit;
}
```

Or apply it to all links:

```
<a href="...">Hello</a>
a:hover{
    color:inherit;
}
```